# Doubt in solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Here, [Asymptotic behaviour / non-linear ODE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1592500/asymptotic-behaviour-non-linear-ode)

The answer Fabian said that $y = t^2$ is a solution of the following non-linear ODE:

$-(y')^2 + (2-a)ty' +2ay =0$ for $a>2$

It is easy to show it.

But how I can deduce this result?

Thanks

Comment: I think the trick here is to try to look for solutions of the form $y=t^p$. Alternatively differentiating and setting $u=y'$ gives an equation that can be separated.

Comment: Sometimes knowing how to guess well is the best approach. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's often a good idea to check a differential equation for polynomial solutions.  If $y$ is a polynomial of degree $d$, $(y')^2$ has degree $2(d-1)$ while the other terms have degree $d$, so this can only be a solution if $d \le 2$.  Substitute $y = A t^2 + B t + C$, collect coefficients of powers of $t$, and it's easy to see that you need $A=1, B=0, C=0$.